# Email Contact Form redirection in IE8

Tags: forms

After recently testing a form using 'Email Contact Form' on IE8 I found that the redirect page does not work at all. It just sits there on the standard EE 'Thank You!' panel and does nothing. It seems to load my 'Thank You' page cause the link on the EE 'Thank You' page (see attached) panel does not work but my cursor detects content from my 'Thank You' page even though it is not visible. Has anyone else had any problems with this kind of thing at all and with IE8.

[image]

Comment: Does the system messages template have {meta_refresh} in it? What happens when you click the 'click here…' link?

Comment: No it does not ... I goes a little odd and the link does not work and it sort of loads my thank page behind it in a broken kind of way. This only happens in IE8.

Answer (score 1):

With a little jQuery AJAX knowledge, you can avoid the "Thank You" page & redirection entirely by using [this tutorial](http://www.highintegritydesign.com/blog/articles/creating-a-modern-ajax-contact-form-in-expressionengine) and [accompanying jQuery script](https://github.com/northk/ee-ajax-contact-form).  This approach has worked well for me.

Comment: I will take a look at this. Thanks for you input.